# Multiple Routers, Failover, DHCP and multiple gateways. NOT WAN-failover

Tags: router, dhcp, wifi, gateway

I've had a look around google and this forum but could not find an answer to my question. So probably one of you can help me a little.

My intended setup is:

- Router R1:

  - wan connection to isp.
  - connected backup server.
  - provides some wireless SSID.
  - other connected devices like printer, laptop, etc. both wired and wireless.

- Router R2:

  - no wan connection to isp but connected to R2.
  - connects mp3-streamer and music server.
  - also serves as a wireless access point with same SSID.
  - other than described connections only wireless connections.

I would like to be able to control music even if R1 is off, e.g. with no internet connection.
On the other hand I would like to access internet also in the case that R2 is off, i.e. no music access.
Last but not least I would like to stream internet radio, i.e., R1 and R2 are on, and music is streamed from internet to R1 to R2 to streamer.

I would like to realize all this using DHCP (also using static assignments) so i do not have to configure statically on android, laptop, etc.
So my questions are:

- Can I make DHCP provide a list of two default gateways R1,R2?
- In order to make clients fallback to other gateway if currently assigned gateway is turned off?

Comment: Why are you using a router for a no connection to internet? Is your servers in an own subnet?

Comment: Sometimes i'd like to listen to music while NOT being connected to the internet :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use static routes; 
I.e tell that everything that matches 192.168.10.0/25 should be sent to R2, but everything else (i.e. the internet) should be sent to R1.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Is this something that I can configure via DHCP?

Comment: Moreover, does that allow to access e.g. the printer connected to R1 while R2 is turned off?